# How to remove duplicates in a column and keep the last occurence?

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-analysis, data-cleaning, m

My input is this table :

```
category    id
YYY          A
XXX          B
XXX          A
XXX          C
ZZZ          A
```

When I select the `id` column and choose remove duplicates, it keeps the first occurence of ids :

```
category    id
YYY          A
XXX          B
XXX          C
```

But I need to keep the last occurence. PS: the order is important.

```
category    id
XXX          B
XXX          C
ZZZ          A
```

Do you guys know how to do it ?

Here is the code and example table I used :

```vb
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document(
            Binary.Decompress(
                Binary.FromText(
                    "i45WioyMVNJRclSK1YlWioiIALKdkNjI4s5gdlRUFEQ8FgA=",
                    BinaryEncoding.Base64
                ),
                Compression.Deflate
            )
        ),
        let
            _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
        in
            type table [category = _t, id = _t]
    ),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Source,
        {{"category", type text}, {"id", type text}}
    ),
    #"Doublons supprimés" = Table.Distinct(#"Type modifié", {"id"})
in
    #"Doublons supprimés"
```

Comment: What about doing a descending sort by date?

Comment: Sometimes the date column is not a date and just some arbitrary text categories.

Comment: How would anyone know that a date may not be a date based on your example?

Comment: I didn't express it well. I'll update my example so you can understand.

Comment: Add an index column, sort the index column by descending, then remove duplicates

Answer (score 2):

When PQ removes duplicates, there is no guarantee as to which of the duplicates will be retained. See Microsoft Help for [Table.Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-distinct)

To avoid this, you need to Buffer the table.
And to return the last, you can reverse the table before buffering.

So your modified code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document(
            Binary.Decompress(
                Binary.FromText(
                    "i45WMjDUByIjAyMTJR0lR6VYHaCQEZKQE6YQFlXOECFjVFWxAA==",
                    BinaryEncoding.Base64
                ),
                Compression.Deflate
            )
        ),
        let
            _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
        in
            type table [date = _t, id = _t]
    ),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"date", type date}, {"id", type text}}),
    #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Type modifié", each [date] <> null and [date] <> ""),

#"Reverse and Buffer" = Table.Buffer(Table.ReverseRows(#"Lignes filtrées")),

    #"Doublons supprimés" = Table.Distinct(#"Reverse and Buffer", {"id"})
in
    #"Doublons supprimés"
```

returns:
[image]

Or, using your second example:
[image]

*If the `id` order in the results column is also important, you can probably just reverse the table again*

Comment: Do you know if List.Last would need to be buffered in my solution out of interest?

Comment: @DavideBacci I don't know. But I do see this caveat in the `Table.Group` documentation: `"This function does not guarantee the ordering of the rows it returns."`

Answer (score 0):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(
        Json.Document(
            Binary.Decompress(
                Binary.FromText(
                    "i45WMjDUByIjAyMTJR0lR6VYHaCQEZKQE6YQFlXOECFjVFWxAA==",
                    BinaryEncoding.Base64
                ),
                Compression.Deflate
            )
        ),
        let
            _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
        in
            type table [date = _t, id = _t]
    ),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"date", type date}, {"id", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Type modifié", {"id"}, {{"All", each _, type table [date=nullable date, id=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.Last([All][date]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above - suggest you add an Index column, then sort that on descending, then remove duplicates.